# Why is my pycharm project loading not loading up?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

When i create a new pycharm project it doesn't open it is just left with a blank screen and i can't click on it e.g.:

[image]

tester main is an example where i can open it, testerdag is a projectname i cannot open. I have checked the .idea folder for testdag and the worksapce.xml is different. I have tried deleting the .idea folder and reopening but same issue.. what is going on?

Even when i create a new python project from file=--> new project it still does not open

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the logs/thread dumps attached, refer to https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085 and https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544899.

Comment: where can i get my logs?

Comment: All the information is available if you follow the provided links.